# How can I get the number that match with another number

Tags: lua

I want to get the number that match with another number. I tried this but I got nil:

`string.match(v.id, user_id)`

Comment: provide in and ouput so we can see why you get nil

Answer (score 1):

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match)

> `string.match (s, pattern [, init])`
> Looks for the first match of the pattern (see §6.4.1) in the string s.
> If it finds one, then match returns the captures from the pattern;
> otherwise it returns fail. If pattern specifies no captures, then the
> whole match is returned. A third, optional numeric argument init
> specifies where to start the search; its default value is 1 and can be
> negative.

`string.match(v.id, user_id)` will return nil if your pattern `user_id` does not match `v.id`

If you just want to find out if two strings are equal use `==`

```
print(v.id == user_id)
```

If you want to find `user_id` in `v.id` use `string.find` or `string.match`

```
print(string.find(v.id, user_id))
print(string.match(v.id, user_id))
```

Anything else would require more informatin in your post.

If you receive nil then `user_id` is nowhere in `v.id`. Note that both must match exactly! So `123` would not match `12-3` or something.